# Is there an idiom for the phrase 'that's not what I meant'?

Tags: idioms, american-english, idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiom for the phrase

> 'that's not what I meant'

and Google seems to be of no help whatsoever.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I've edited your question to improve appearance etc, but I recommend you [edit] it further to add *context* - e.g. is this for your general interest, or a book you're writing? Describe the situation you might use it in. Presumably you want an idiomatic expression to *replace* the sentence (rather than what I first thought - you wanting an idiom for the *description* of such an expression). For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: In what sense? Are you saying that you expressed yourself poorly, i.e., “that’s not what I meant to say, let me express it better”; or that the other person is talking about something else than you, i.e., “what are you talking about? That’s not what I said at all”?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the idiomatic expression:

***[a different kettle of fish](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a-different-kettle-of-fish).***

> If you say that something is a different kettle of fish, you mean that it is very different from another related thing that you are talking about.

( Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

> You're talking **apples and oranges**.

"A comparison of apples and oranges occurs when two items or groups of items are compared that cannot be practically compared. The idiom, comparing apples and oranges, refers to the apparent differences between items which are popularly thought to be incomparable or incommensurable, such as apples and oranges."
<sub>*source:* [wikipedia - Apples and Oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Generally we would say that what was meant has become "wrong"

> You got **that wrong**, I meant …
>   You've got **me/that all wrong**, I meant …
>   That went down the **wrong way**, I meant …
>   Your barking up the **wrong tree**, I meant …
>   You got the **wrong end of the stick**, I meant …
>   You've got the **wrong idea** about ###, I meant …

If I'm not wrong, there are many others.